# matplotlib Invalid rgba arg but I am passing the correct arguement I "think"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

I am getting the error below though the data looks fine

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['g']" to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "('g',)" sequence length is 1; must be 3 or 4
```

I load it into the tuple here last parameter

```
sector_format = {
'0': ["Materials","o",'lightcoral'],
'1':["Information Technology","^",'g'],
'2':[ "Financials","v",'r'],
'3':["Consumer Discretionary","s",'c'],
'4':["Industrials","d",'m'],
'5':["Health Care","8",'y'],
'6':["Energy",">",'k'],
'7':["emerging markets","h",'lightgrey'],
'8':["Consumer Staples","|",'lightblue']
}
```

I use it here where final_np[test:test+1,3] contains the color value

```
ax1.plot(final_np[prior_test:test,1],final_np[prior_test:test,2],lw = 0.5,color=final_np[test:test+1,3],marker=r"$ {} $".format(final_np[test:test+1,0]),markersize=final_np[test:test+1,6])
```

If I print out the test data ( here is an example)

```
print("test data ", final_np[prior_test:test,1],final_np[prior_test:test,2],final_np[test:test+1,0],final_np[test:test+1,6],final_np[test:test+1,3])
```

I get the value passed to color as 'r' which seems ok to me. here is an example of a test print

```
test data  [datetime.date(2015, 8, 10) datetime.date(2015, 8, 14)
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 17) datetime.date(2015, 8, 21)
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 24) datetime.date(2015, 8, 28)
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 31)] [64.0 90.0 89.0 8.0 5.0 50.0 53.0]
 ['^VIX']    [20] ['r']
```

what am I missing please?

Comment: Can you turn this into a runable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi AGAIN Tcaswell sorry no I tried that but it got very messy VERY quickly. I was hoping the error message contained something I missed. Maybe it's formatted incorrectly and I am not seeing it.  I read the matplotlib docs, looked at the examples and all seems well but obviously I have screwed up somehow. Thanks again for looking at this and I understand my question is lacking,

Comment: The error message `Invalid rgba arg "['g']"` suggests you're passing an array with a single string value in it, where a string value alone is expected.

Comment: Hi cphlewis I tried color = str(final_np[test:test+1,3]) and no luck. thanks for the great suggest and for looking at my problem

Comment: What about `color=final_np[test:test+1,3][0]`?

Comment: Print out the values you're passing as arguments to `plot` before you call `plot`.

Comment: @cphlewis YOU ARE A STAR!!! made me look again at the error IN DETAIL this time and you were right. I made the mod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cphlewis YOU ARE A STAR!!!

made me look again at the error IN DETAIL this time and you were right. I made the mod

```
 jcolor  = ''.join(final_np[test:test+1,3])
```

and called plot with

```
ax1.plot(final_np[prior_test:test,1],final_np[prior_test:test,2],lw = 0.5,color=jcolor,marker=r"$ {} $".format(final_np[test:test+1,0]),markersize=final_np[test:test+1,6])
```

AND all was well in the garden. Thanks @cphlewis